# How to charge two 3.7 V Li-ion batteries in series with TP4056 charging module?

Tags: arduino, batteries, battery-charging, lipo, tp4056

I use two 3.7 V Li-ion batteries in series for an Arduino Nano. To charge them, I use a TP4056 Type-C charging module, but it just charges one of the batteries. If I use two TP4056 charging modules and connect them in parallel, and the output is in series can I charge two of them and get 7.4 V output?

Comment: You need to rewire them to be in series once the parallel charging has been done.

Comment: You could also consider running the Nano on 3.0V thus using 2P batteries https://ba0sh1.com/2013/03/30/tutorial-3-3v-hacking-for-arduino-nano/

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understand what you're proposing, this will not work because if you connect the outputs in series then the GND pin of the first output will be connected to the BAT pin of the second output. Therefore it is not actually GND but rather 4.2V. This will effectively make the voltage output of your first device 0V. Here's a very rough sketch.
[image]