# Using two TP4056 modules to charge two cells in series

Tags: charge, ups, tp4056

[image: charging in series 2 lion bats]

Here's an attempt to get use two modules of charges to charge and protect each of its own batteries connected in series.

Adding back-to-back P-mosfets and a shottky diode converts the whole system into UPS.

What would possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> What would possibly go wrong?

BOOM!

This is [a classic mistake that rookies make](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/607949/how-to-charge-two-3-7-v-li-ion-batteries-in-series-with-tp4056-charging-module).

This solution does not work because these charging modules are not isolated. That circuit makes a direct short across the lower cell.

[image]

What that is pointed out to them, the workaround that rookies propose is to add an isolated DC-DC 5 V converter to power one of the modules. Yes, that will work. That wastes power in the DC-DC converter (which may not be too bad) and by having two sets of MOSFETs for protection instead of one (which also may not be too bad). But it's noticeably more complex and less reliable than using the proper solution: a [2S charge and protector BMS module](https://www.adeept.com/li-ion-battery-charger-m-2s2a_p0374.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! But yet it was a catchy one. Didn't see where the boom was